# .net Core System.ValueTuple

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

My application is MVC Core c#, I return from a method in a generic repository two items, object and string:

```
   public object PostWebApi(TObject model, string url, string dir)
        {...
    return (model, msg);}
```

In the controller I use

```
  var data = _studentService.PostWebApi(WebApiDirectory());
 return View(data)
```

Passing the model to the view, I get error

```
The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.ValueTuple
```

[image]

On debug, the returned object has two items, the model and string.
Can't figure out how to just pass the model, item1, to the view.

Comment: can you show the code for your view?  It looks like your view is expecting a different type

Comment: @model WebUI.Models.Student.  The method returns the model and the string which I want to use for ViewBag.  The challenge is how to split item1 and item2.

Comment: @GiladGreen you need to install the new version for c#7. Install-Package System.ValueTuple -Version 4.4.0. It worked, my app is Core 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning the value tuple to your view when you do `return View(data)`, where `data` is the result of the value tuple. You need to return data.Item1.

For one, you should name the return values of your tuple inside your PostWebApi method for readability purposes.. So instead of something like `public (Student, String) PostwebApi()`, you want something like `public (Student student, String msg) PostWebApi()`.

Then inside your controller, you can do `return View(data.student);` If you need the other portion of your tuple, you can access it via `data.msg`.

Comment: Thank you.  I changed the return:
 public Object PostWebApi(TObject model, string url, string dir){...
 var result = new { student = model, message = msg };
                return (result);}
It returns: data {student = {WebUI.Models.Student}, message = "{\"id\":23,\"lastName}
Could not use data.student, get an error (no reference),

Comment: So debugging right before the ```return View(data.student);``` shows student having a value, but inside the RazorView the ViewModel is null?

Comment: I can't use data.student in the controller.  The error is the object I am returning does not have a reference for students; I think the error is due to returning an object?

Comment: Your problem is that you're not correctly using a ValueTuple, you're returning an anonymous object. You need to make your method look like ```public (Student student, string msg) PostWebApi(TObject model, string url, string dir )``` and then for your return, do ```return (model, msg)```

Comment: I edited the question.  I am using the method in a generic repository.  I tried your suggestion but could not use the model Student as a TObject. Thanks

Comment: The TObject that you're passing into the PostWebApi method is a Student object? It would help if you used generics here. ```public (T model, string msg) PostWebApi<T>(TObject model, string url, string dir```....```return ((T) model, msg);``` Then you can call it as such.. ```var data = _studentsService.PostWebApi<Student>(WebApiDirectory());``` This will leave you with ```data.model``` which is of the generic type you passed in, and ```data.msg```.

Comment: I used public (object,string) PostWebApi(TObject model, string url, string dir).  And data.item1. Worked great, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

another way may be that you change the view model to

```
@model System.ValueTuple<WebUI.Models.Student, object>
```

and access your values in **Item1** and **Item2** proprieties

Comment: Interesting, will give it a try. Thank you